# How to change path / src inside the iframe dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As you can see if you run the code snippet.
You will see "openstreetmap" hyperlink.

If you click it. you will open a new document with a different URL path at the browser level.
I want to get this new "URL" / "path" / document inside the iframe tag.

I have been trying to find a solution in many places.
but it seems like an impossible mission!

can some brave guy, help me to do some magic in js / jquery.
I was trying with sandbox attribute to prevent top navigation.
but it feels like nothing is working.

Thanks!

```html
<iframe 
src="https://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=-0.004017949104309083%2C51.47612752641776%2C0.00030577182769775396%2C51.478569861898606&layer=mapnik">
</iframe>
```

Comment: if you understand the principle that you cannot change a web page from another web page, you would understand that you cannot change the content of an iframe, even from its parent page

Comment: the link has a `target="_blank"`, and due to cross origin restrictions its **not possible** to change it to `target="_self"`

Comment: “It seems like an impossible mission”… because it is. If people can modify content of any iframed webpage on a whim then we’d be in so much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The target of `<a>` should have the name of the `<iframe>`:

```html
<p><a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=-0.004017949104309083%2C51.47612752641776%2C0.00030577182769775396%2C51.478569861898606&layer=mapnik" target="map">Open map</a></p>
<iframe name="map"></iframe>
```

You can also use JavaScript:

```js
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.querySelector('iframe').src = e.target.href;
});
```

```html
<p><a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=-0.004017949104309083%2C51.47612752641776%2C0.00030577182769775396%2C51.478569861898606&layer=mapnik">Open map</a></p>
<iframe></iframe>
```